# File content not getting displayed correctly in div

Tags: php, html, file-get-contents

I'm trying to display the content of a php file to a div.

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="highlight">
<?php
echo file_get_contents( "/path/test.php" );
?>
</div>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
require_once (lib.php');

/*
some comments here
*/
session_cache_limiter('private, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
@ob_start();
@session_start();

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); 

// INCLUDES
define('FPDF_FONTPATH', "path/font/");
// print_r($_GET);
?>
.......................
```

But the content in the div is displaying from this line only : `// print_r($_GET);`. I need to display the entire content of the file.

Can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check the sourcecode in the browser?

Comment: Tip: `highlight_file()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php

Comment: The opening `<?php` tag is seen as a HTML tag (inside the div).

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions..Checked the source code. There the content is shown but those missing lines are shown in green color.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions..actually I need to save the file contents displayed on the editable div. But if I use `highlight_file`, it will return the contents along with highlight styles. Is there anyway to avoid that?

Comment: There is nothing in your script to display, what do you exactly want to display?

Comment: @AhmedGinani..I need to display the entire php file content/code.

Comment: show_source() can help ?

Comment: @AhmedGinani [`show_source()`](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/function.show-source.php) is an alias for `highlight_file()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the HTML parser of your browser sees `<?php` as an HTML element it will be commented out. You have to convert `<` and `>` to their equivalent HTML entities.

You can do this using [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) (using `<pre></pre>` to keep the new lines from the actual file):

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="highlight">
    <pre><?php // this should be directly after pre to prevent white-space from appearing before the code from the file
        echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents( "43677696_test.php" ));
    ?>
    </pre>
</div>
```

You can see the output [here](https://tomudding.nl/tests/stackoverflow/43677696.php).

Comment: Thanks..This works. If I use `highlight_file()` instead of `file_get_contents()`, is there anyway to remove codes related to it while saving the div content back to the file?

Comment: I don't know a simple solution for that, you'll have to parse the content of `highlight_file()` (second parameter should be `true`, see documentation) and then you'll have to remove all the code blocks (possibly using regex).